# Call to a member function find() on a non-object - cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I am a beginner in cakePHP. Getting the following error

> Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object    File:
>   /var/www/html/cakephp/app/Model/Post.php
>   Line: 11

There are many related posts regarding the error, but I was unable to track the problem by referring those.

my model Post.php

```
<?php

class Post extends AppModel {
public $validate = array(
'title' => array('rule' => 'notBlank'),
'body' => array('rule' => 'notBlank'));
public $belongsTo = 'Category';
public function actual(){ 
return $this->Post->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Post.deleted' => 0)));
}
}
?>
```

my index() in Controller

```
public function index() 
{
    $actual = $this->Post->actual();
    $this->Post->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array ('limit' => 5);
    $this->set('actuals', $this->paginate());
}
```

I am trying to implement soft delete logic. If a user clicks on delete, the flag in deleted column in database changes to 1 for the appropriate data. And hence, in general I have to display data with deleted = 0.

I was able to achieve it by putting an if condition in my index view, but that is inconvenient, I want to filter the data at Model itself (if it is possible) 
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

**Update**
In my model I changed

```
return $this->Post->find
```

to

```
return $this->find
```

now the error is gone, but It is showing all the data, even the deleted ones!

Comment: It comes when you miss your model name .
 have  you written this code in controller??
public $uses = array('Post'); //Model name

Answer (score 1):

Your model Post is correct, but it's not correct in controller.

Solution 1 [Simple]:

- Model: not change. The function 'actuals' can use for another purpose, but not needed in this case.
- Controller:

  ```
  public function index() 
  {
      $this->Post->recursive = 0;
      $this->paginate = array (
          'limit' => 5,
          'conditions' => array(
              array('Post.deleted' => 0)
          )
      );
      $this->set('actuals', $this->paginate());
  }
  ```

Solution 2:

- Model:

  ```
  <?php

  class Post extends AppModel {
      public $findMethods = array('actuals' => true);

      public $validate = array(
          'title' => array('rule' => 'notBlank'),
          'body' => array('rule' => 'notBlank'));
      public $belongsTo = 'Category';
      protected function _findActuals($state, $query, $results = array()){ 
          if ($state === 'before') {
              $query['conditions']['Post.deleted'] = false;

              return $query;
          }

          return $results;
      }
  }
  ?>
  ```
- Controller:

  ```
   public function index() 
   { 
        $this->Post->recursive = 0;
        $this->paginate = array ('limit' => 5, 'findType' => 'actuals');
        $this->set('actuals', $this->paginate());
   }
  ```

Ref: [Cakephp 2.x - Custom find types](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#creating-custom-find-types)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had implemented the code I just posted which is similar to your Solution 1 ! Will try to implement the Solution 2 and check as well ! Thanks again

Comment: The solution 2 just in case complex query and reuse. For simple query, use simple way :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the output

```
public function index() 
    {
        $this->Post->recursive = 0;
        $this->Paginator->settings = array('conditions' => array('Post.deleted' => 0),'limit' => 5);        
        $this->set('actuals', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }
```

The above changes gave me a normal output, Still haven't been able to filter data at model though. If you think this is in-convenient as well please let me know, I want to learn efficient coding :) thanks !